# CSS Background URL source not setting image as background

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3

Background image url works fine locally but when uploaded to AWS S3 bucket the background image does not work.

```
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.7828081916360294) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6007353625043768) 0%), url(../img/micheile-henderson-t05q7TZObzc-unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
```

What's interesting is that when I inspect the live website using chrome dev tools the `..` within `../img/micheile-henderson-t05q7TZObzc-unsplash.jpg` disappears and if I manually add the `..` the background image appears.

Why when I upload is it losing the `..` ?

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess it's probably an issue with the relative image link.  Maybe try entering the full url to the file in AWS bucket?

Comment: I think this is an AWS issue as I tried changing some basic HTML files and the changes didn't appear..first time this has happened. I thought new files being uploaded changed straight away as they have done previously